# Export Table from Mathematica into specific cells Excel

Tags: export, excel, version-6

How can I export a table to Excel - to specific cells, e.g. D1-E2?

Background: I want to compare results, and it's easier to have the results on one spreadsheet.

I'm using *Mathematica* 6.

This is my notebook so far:

```
ResultsV = Grid[{  {"result1", result1},  {"result2", result2}}] 
Export["results.pdf", ResultsV]
```

This table should appear twice in the spreadsheet, as some parameters differ.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you create an Excel file manually, and then use `Import["file.xls", "Rules"]` and see what you can learn from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For  example:

```
(* some data *)
pts = Range[10]^4;
f1 = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
f2 = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
t1 = Join[{{"x", "f1[]"}}, Table[{x, f1@x}, {x, 1.5, 4.5, 1}]];
t2 = Join[{{"x", "f2[]"}}, Table[{x, f2@x}, {x, 1.5, 4.5, 1}]];
data = Join @@@ Transpose@{t1, t2};

(* Transformation from Excel "A1" notation to indexes *)
at = {FromDigits@ToExpression@Flatten[StringCases[Characters[#], _?DigitQ], 1], 
      FromDigits[Flatten[ToCharacterCode /@ StringCases[Characters[#], _?UpperCaseQ] - 
       First@ToCharacterCode["A"] + 1, 2], Length@CharacterRange["A", "Z"]]} &;

(* Generation of a sparse array with the required block positioning *)
sp[data_List, pos_String] := SparseArray[
                              Flatten@MapIndexed[#2 + at@pos - 1 -> #1 &, data, {2}],  
                            Automatic, ""];

(* export the data to Excel*)
Export["c:\\test2.xls", sp[data, "B3"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How does this show filling e.g. D1-E2?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In a previous incarnation of this answer (you may look at it in the edit history) I posted a way to convert from "excel coordinates" to indexes. As I didn't get a reply from the OP, I am trying now to show him a different thing. Sorry, but if it isn't this one, I am unable to understand what is he looking for.

Comment: I believe the idea is to do `Export["file.xls", data]` and have certain columns filled in; no time now to talk about it though, sorry.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard did it. Not sure if this is what the OP wanted, but anyway ..

Comment: I'm new in Mathematica - I still do not understand in detail what you did, belisarius (nevertheless, Thanks, I'll work it out).

It may be not exactly what I am looking for: I run my computations for different cases and at the end of the programm, I export the data. Running the file twice (for the second case, eg), I'd like to write the data into the already existing xls file that contains the results of the first case.

Comment: @StefanieSchubert You could read the previous file with `Import["xxx.xls", "Rules"]`, and merge those rules with the result of my `sp[]` function. Then Export the result. See the help for ArrayRules

Comment: @belisarius, I could replicate your code but it breaks when exporting using the multiple sheets syntax: Export["mfile2.xls", {"m Data" -> m, "n Data" -> n}]; in the latter case what is exported is the unevaluated expression string at "A1".

Comment: @alancalvitti I think it's a bug

Comment: @belisarius, ok, I'll contact WRI. By the way, is the cast to `SparseArray` necessary?

Comment: @belisarius, actually, I can't replicate your behavior using `at` and `sp` even in the single-sheet case, with a single column of data (ie `Dimension` == 1)

Comment: @belisarius, also if the Excel sheet already contains data, it is overwritten (with blanks), even if new data is exported into blank cells.

Comment: @alancalvitti The sparse array is just a convenient way to load the matrix by its indexes