# Create a hyperlink in an array to be exported as Excel file

Tags: export, excel, hyperlink

I want to create an Excel file with some data and hyperlinks to a file. The goal is that in the end you can click in Excel the link and the file opens. The Excel file is to be exported from *Mathematica*. I tried this:

```
ClearAll[hyper]
hyper[name_, ort_] := "=HYPERLINK(\"" <> ort <> "\";\"" <> name <> "\")"
hhh = {{"a", "a", hyper["XXX", "D:\\Temp"]}}
Export["D:\\11.xlsx", hhh]
```

When I open the Excel file I have to go to the cell with the hyperlink, then go to the end of the hyperlink and have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then it works. As there will be many links in my real Excel file I need a solution that works straight away. Can the "<kbd>Enter</kbd>" part be added from *Mathematica*? Other solutions?

Comment: You could use JLink and follow, e.g., [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_hyperlink.htm).

Comment: Uufff, I was hoping for something easy directly out of MMA.

Comment: the semi-colon should be a comma. (doesnt fix it though)

Comment: I think `Hyperlink["xxx", url]` is now recognized when exporting to XLSX.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little work around that is working. Do it as shown above but use:

```
Export["D:\\11.dat", hhh]
```

and then import this to Excel. Yes, it is a little breaking the rules as it is not directly an Excel file. In addtion the links are working but not formated in the usual (blue, underlined) way. So some post processing is needed.

Comment: Could you add more details? What version of Excel are you using, and how do you import the file? With Excel 2003 this solution doesn't work.

Comment: The Excel Version is 2016. For opening the .dat file I just go to open and select that .dat file. Then I use Tabstopps as Separation marker. The data Format is Standard. After that the xxx is in the cell visible and if you click on it the Explorer window with the according Folder opens. The XXX does not have the style of the link but it works as a link.

Comment: Thank you, it does work with Excel 2003! I use Russian localized version of Excel, so I have to replace `HYPERLINK` with `ГИПЕРССЫЛКА` in the definition of your function `hyper`, and then it works.

Comment: You can be interested in a way to automatize importing of .dat files via the `Data ► Import from external source... ► Import data...` Excel's menu item which I describe in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15839/280) answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64):

```
Export["test.xls", Hyperlink["D:\\Temp\\input.txt"]]
```

This also works:

```
Export["test.xls", Hyperlink["Open input.txt", "D:\\Temp\\input.txt"]]
```

In the exported Excel file the hyperlink is clickable immediately after opening the file.

Note that due to a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143869/280) for exporting as XLSX you need to use only forward slashes in the file paths:

```
Export["test.xlsx", Hyperlink["Open input.txt", "D:/Temp/input.txt"]]
```