# Problem with Excel export with specific hyperlink

Tags: bugs, export, excel, hyperlink

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 12.2**

---

Exporting `Hyperlink[]` to XLSX works usually just fine, but with this particular link

```
problem = Hyperlink["http://www.faulbach.de/komxpress/DynDox.asp?Orgid={F527CBB0-4493-42D0-AAD6-149A10DD8D88}&LinkID={58899F1E-D42B-481F-B507-C3A9B136A780}"];
Export["myfile.xlsx", problem]
```

I get the error message

```
Export::fmterr: Invalid XLSX format.
```

Other Hyperlinks that cannot be exported to Excel:
[Link1](http://www.metropolregion-nordwest.de/downloads/datei/OTAwMDAwNDQ4Oy07L3Vzci9sb2NhbC9odHRwZC92aHRkb2NzL2Ntc3gvbWV0cm9wb2xyZWdpb24vbWVkaWVuL2Rva3VtZW50ZS9wcmFlc2VudGF0aW9uX25ldHprb256ZXB0aW9uXzIwMzBbMV0ucGRm/praesentation_netzkonzeption_2030%5B1%5D.pdf), [Link2](http://www.sueddeutsches-institut.de/ENI/PriceWaterhouseCoopers%20%5B2006%5D%20Die%20wirtschaftlichen%20Chancen%20alternativer%20Antriebsenergien%20am%20Beispiel%20des%20Hybridantriebs.pdf), [Link3](http://www.contractawards.eu/#!supplier=%E2%80%9E%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%2091%22%20%D0%95%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%94,%20%D0%95%D0%98%D0%9A%20010652246), [Link4](https://www.kssn.net/include/fileDown.asp?category=stdORG&filename=KACA014_1%7CSPS-KACA014-201719.pdf), [Link5](http://analysis.rs/productlist.php?pstq=1%7C4%7C6%7C0).

I am using "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)".

Comment: Looks like a bug. It works if you `Export` with extension ".xls": `Export["myfile.xls", problem]`.

Comment: It seems that the problem is the presence of "{" and "}" in the URL: removing these symbols makes `Export` working.

Comment: Right, the second URL works. I check again. The workaround with XLS helps a lot.

Comment: I encountered another error when the link contained a space. I thought it would be impossible for an URL to contain a space, but it is not. However, for saving it to xlsx, it needs to be escaped as %20.

Comment: I updated the answer. Have you reported the original bug in `Export`?

Comment: No, I just did report it now. Thanks for the workaround, again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug.

The source of the problem is the presence of symbols `"{"`, `"}"`, `"["`, `"]"` or `"\\"` in the URL (the list may be incomplete).

The simplest (and seemingly universal) workaround is to `Export` as XLS instead of XLSX:

```
Export["myfile.xls", problem]
```

Another method is to escape the problematic symbols (may not work for local file paths):

```
Export["myfile.xlsx", 
 problem /. s_String :> 
   StringReplace[s, {"{" -> "%7B", "}" -> "%7D", "[" -> "%5B", "]" -> "%5D"}]]
```

For local file paths backslashes should be replaced by forward slashes as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143900/280).

---

#### UPDATE

It seems that in the most cases it is sufficient is to pass URL through `URLParse`/`URLBuild` route:

```
urls={
"http://www.faulbach.de/komxpress/DynDox.asp?Orgid={F527CBB0-4493-42D0-AAD6-149A10DD8D88}&LinkID={58899F1E-D42B-481F-B507-C3A9B136A780}",
"http://www.metropolregion-nordwest.de/downloads/datei/OTAwMDAwNDQ4Oy07L3Vzci9sb2NhbC9odHRwZC92aHRkb2NzL2Ntc3gvbWV0cm9wb2xyZWdpb24vbWVkaWVuL2Rva3VtZW50ZS9wcmFlc2VudGF0aW9uX25ldHprb256ZXB0aW9uXzIwMzBbMV0ucGRm/praesentation_netzkonzeption_2030[1].pdf",
"http://www.sueddeutsches-institut.de/ENI/PriceWaterhouseCoopers [2006] Die wirtschaftlichen Chancen alternativer Antriebsenergien am Beispiel des Hybridantriebs.pdf"};

encodedURLs = URLBuild /@ URLParse[urls];

Export["myfile.xlsx", Hyperlink /@ encodedURLs]
```

But it doesn't currently work for URLs containing a `"Fragment"` what may indicate another bug:

```
URLParse["http://www.contractawards.eu/#!supplier=„Интер Бизнес 91\" ЕООД, ЕИК 010652246"]

URLBuild@%
```

> ```
> <|"Scheme" -> "http", "User" -> None, "Domain" -> "www.contractawards.eu", "Port" -> None,
>   "Path" -> {"", ""}, "Query" -> {}, 
>  "Fragment" -> "!supplier=„Интер Бизнес 91\" ЕООД, ЕИК 010652246"|>
>
> "http://www.contractawards.eu/#!supplier=„Интер Бизнес 91\" ЕООД, ЕИК 010652246"
> ```

One can try to use `URLEncode` to force encoding of the `"Fragment"`.

Comment: Interesting, this is an old bug. In Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7x64, when I enter `Export["myfile.xlsx", problem]`, I get the error message `Export::fmterr: Invalid XLS format` (sic! XLS, not XLSX), while the documentation states "Import and Export are fully compatible with the Excel 2007 standard". The input `Export["myfile.xls", problem]` works fine.

Comment: @innaiz Thanks, added this info to the bug header.