# Append new data to excel?

Tags: export

From [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8726/2458) I know that I can export my data from mma into any given position (such as "B3"), but now I want to append new data to the old one.

As an example,

```
old=Table[{i},{i,5}];
Export["test.xls",old];
new=Table[{i^2},{i,5}];
Export["test.xls", sp[new, "B1"]];
```

where the function `sp` is defined in the linked post, but this did not reach my requirement.

Of course, we can merge the `old` and `new` together, but consider the case that the data scale is large, did there any solution?

I think maybe It is thoughtless to choose `xls` as formart, how about others, `mdb`/`txt`?

Comment: `Export` always writes an entire file. There is no mechanism of adding/appending/inserting/modifying an existing file (regardeless of format).

Comment: If you work with some format where it makes sense to append data to the *end* of the file then you can use `OpenAppend` and low level `Write` operations.  Also, I would not use a undocumented/proprietary format such as "xls" for anything unless obviously you need to share data with excel.

Comment: @vanable whats the driver for this?  Bear in mind that XLS is a complex binary format.  You might be able to generate this behaviour using a Linux pipe, but in reality that would be the OS doing the work not MMA.  The suggestion using mdb is feasible if you open it as a database rather than a file but even then you have no control over what the underlying file system is doing.  If you require that kind of delicate append type functionality you are probably better off using the embedded database functionality.  MMA includes the lightweight HSQLDB see-   http://tinyurl.com/ns9v96s

Comment: @george2079, what about CSV?

Comment: yes you can append to CSV using low level write operations.  Do a search I think that's been discussed on this site.